# Laravel api returns 401(guzzle http client and php curl)

Tags: laravel, api, php-curl, guzzle

I am implementing laravel api with 'api_token' method.

API working fine in POSTMAN REST CLIENT and core php curl request.

But i tried to get response in laravel app using Guzzle Http client and native curl method. Both request returns 401 unauthenticated. i used same api_token which i was used to test in postman rest client. Any idea?
Note: Its not a CORS problem.

Answer (score -1):

Its happen because of app cache.

Just `cache:clear` and `config:cache` will resolve this problem!